# Django-Admin: RTF Editor in Django Admin application

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tinymce, rtf

How do Embed an RTF editor (like : [20 Excellent RTF Editors](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)) in Django admin page for all TextFields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is information on the wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) about how to do this for a number of WYSIWYG editors, there are also several apps which add this to Django, [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/). I like using [django-grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) which makes integrating painless and gives the rest of the admin a facelift as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com/) package as well. It supports many different WYSIWYG editors (including famous CKEditor as well). It is very easy to integrate and very well documented.